# PHPStorm File template variables

Tags: phpstorm

I want to create my own file templates. However something is wrong with variables, since I am prompted for such variables as namespace. Quick example:

```
<?php
namespace ${NAMESPACE};

class ${NAME} 
{

}
```

This prompts me for both namespace and name, while I should only provide a file name. How can I make PHPStorm to auto-detect its [dedicated variables](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/file-template-variables.html)?

I am using 7.1.3 version on latest OSX.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can I make PHPStorm to auto-detect its dedicated variables?

You cannot.

`${NAMESPACE}` is pre-defined/pre-filled only in **bundled templates** where PHP plugin provides special support for it. In all other cases it is treated as **ordinary** variable.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-21711

---

**UPDATE: 2020-01-28**

The aforementioned ticket is now resolved.

You can now select custom template when using "New PHP Class/Trait/Interface" dialog. `${NAMESPACE}` variable now gets taken from that dialog field (where it auto-detected based on your Source Roots settings and you can edit it manually if needed) and passed into the actual template.

Comment: That's sad. Makes creating own templates rather useless. Thanks for a quick answer.

Comment: Well ... you can edit bundled template. And with installed **File Template Variables** plugin you can make it quite customisable on per project level. Not ideal and I do not know how different your templates should be .. but something to look into. (P.S. Templates support `if-else` logic ...)

Comment: @LazyOne I have tried File Template Variables plugin, but the ${NAMESPACE} variable is still not working. It does not insert namespace automatically. So did you manage to make PHPStorm insert namespace and not type it manually? If so, how?

Comment: @LazyOne I know how existing $NAMESPACE variable works, you don't have to tell me that. I can see myself :) What I want is to know if it is possible to have namespace automatically added and not type it manually. As it appears, this very much needed functionality is not implemented and so many users are not taking advantage of custom file templates. The ticket is open for more than 2 years and nothing has been done about it. What can we do? Did you post your vote/comment already there? If not - just do it. Now. Thanks.

Comment: As a __workaround__, you click `Create new PHP Class`, copy the `NAMESPACE`, then paste it in your template dialog

Comment: You can now select a template when creating new PHP Class which solves the problem.

Comment: It works when you use New -> PHP Class. But when I copy PHP Class template to my own just to add child templates (multiple files with one click) then I need to type namespace manually again. How to apply this dialog to custom template with multiple PHP files?

Comment: @ArielBogdziewicz This works only when "New Class" **DIALOG WINDOW** is appearing; because it's that window that provides such extra variables (for that specific case). For your case (multi-file template) it will NOT work as that dialog window is NOT involved. **P.S.** Will it create multiple files if you use that New Class and select your template there? I think it will work for the main file and not for the child ones; still worth checking if you have not done yet.

Comment: @LazyOne Indeed it allows to select my custom template in this dialog. However it creates only main file. So I confirm your theory.

Comment: @ArielBogdziewicz Considering how it all works (how that variable gets provided) it's expected behaviour. Regardless, feel free to submit a Feature Request to cover your case somehow at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI -- maybe JetBrains devs will come up with some idea one day on how such a case should be handled (I believe this will be a low priority on their system though (my expectations))